# xbmc jsonrpc and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, xbmc

Basically I'm trying to poll my xbmc using the jsonrpc with the following:

```
_data = '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"VideoLibrary.GetMovies", "id":"1"}';
_XBMCHOST = "http://192.168.0.140:8080/jsonrpc";

$.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: _data,
      jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
      url: _XBMCHOST,
      success: function () {
          console.log( 'here here here');
      },

      error:function( result ){
         console.log( result );
         console.log('error!!!');
      }
  });
```

But I keep getting back *parsererror*. I can however run the same post successfully through curl and get back the desired results, ie:

```
curl -i -X POST -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"VideoLibrary.GetMovies", "id":"1"}' http://192.168.0.140:8080/jsonrpc
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try putting `" "` around the properties? You might be using a reserved word.

Comment: Does XBMC support jsonp? I don't know, but a quick search doesn't yield anything that suggests it does. Try the curl snippet with the url `http://192.168.0.140:8080/jsonrpc?callback=jsonp_callback` to check it works

Comment: @seanja didn't seem to make a difference.

@rob curl command worked fine with the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curl command you are using is a `POST` whereas the jquery command is a `GET`. Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: _data,
  jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
  url: _XBMCHOST,
  type: 'post', //make this a post instead of a get
  success: function () {
      console.log( 'here here here');
  },

  error:function( result ){
     console.log( result );
     console.log('error!!!');
  }
});
```

Comment: good catch, but didn't fix the problem. After some searching looks like this is a browser limitation - http://www.johnhamelink.com/2010/07/combat-crossdomain-post-problems-ajax/

Comment: Well... yes... that would be a problem, there is a way around it though apparently http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/

Comment: You saved my night !!!!
I was trying to reach xbmc api with javascript and your solution is perfect !